# Calculating quantity needed from order sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an order sheet to calculate what items are needed to be produced based on quantity ordered and quantity on hand(QOH).

What I am having trouble with is calculating the correct quantity needed.

- If quantity ordered is 0, quantity needed should be 0.
- If quantity ordered is >0, and QOH < quantity ordered, quantity needed should be the difference in a positive integer.
- if quantity ordered is >0, and QOH ≧ quantity ordered, quantity needed should be 0.

Any idea on how this would be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the quantity ordered cell is named `Ordered` and the quantity on hand cell is named `QOH`, you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(Ordered=0,0,MAX(0,Ordered-QOH))
```

The result will be 0 if the quantity ordered is zero; it will be the number needed (`Ordered-QOH`) if that number is positive, otherwise, it will be 0.